Morning cartoon show from late 80s, early 90s; boy's family turned to stone
I hope someone can help me.   I remember a cartoon show that was pretty cool where a boy's family is turned to stone and he has to journey somewhere far away - is never like just around the corner - to rescue them from their ...   Stonedom. (?)
  I distinctly remember a small Dragon that sat on his shoulder every now and then - a la Dany Targaryen - and it was MAD FOR POMEGRANATES!

Sounds like Conan the Adventurer from 1992. From IMDb:

Young Cimmerian barbarian Conan and his allies must stop snake-man wizard Wrath-Amon and his snake-men army from resurrecting evil serpent god Set. Conan must also destroy the evil wizard's ring that turned his family into stone.

Conan had a young phoenix companion on his shoulder called Needle who really liked pomegranates; here's a clip of him diving head first into pomegranate pulp (and the end credits):




Thank you very much Mr.  Heisenberg.   Yes that sounds very likely to be my lost show.   Unfortunately I can't see the clip of needle plunging his head into the pomegranate!

@GarthmanGman You can see that clip here and the show's intro here. If this is the correct answer, don't forget to click on the check mark to close it.

That is most certainly it!    Thank you!
